# 403. That’s an error. We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That’s all we know

Tags: android, admob

Hi I have tried some demo ad's from adMob I could successfully display some ad's in my application until yesterday but today when I tried to run the same application it was showing the following :

No GMSG handler found for GMSG: gmsg://mobileads.google.com/jsLoaded?google.afma.Notify_dt=1419570286070
Failed to load ad: 3

so I have tried to login to check my account, then the following message is shown.

**403. That’s an error.
We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That’s all we know.**

please let me know the solution for this issue...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming problem.

Comment: Clear your question by giving me more details if you want answer related to admob.

Comment: when I am trying to login into AdMob account it was showing the following error: 403. That’s an error. We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That’s all we know, so that I was unable to get ad's in my application showing the following error in my log's No GMSG handler found for GMSG: gmsg://mobileads.google.com/jsLoaded?google.afma.Notify_dt=1419570286070 Failed to load ad: 3 , the same application was working fine I am able to display ad's in my application until yesterday but now I am unable to do that because of this issue,I am new to adMob please guide me to solve this issue

Comment: I have gone through my issue the issue is that I was clicking on the ad's that I got from server which should not be done I was unaware of this condition as I was beginner in using adMob application.But I want to know how can I enable live ad's in my application and how can I enable demo ad's in my application please suggest me how to enable demo and live ad's on go as the application will be tested by tester during the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I used to click live ad's even during the development phase so my adMob account is blocked and not able to get any live ad's from adMob server so after some investigation I get to know how can i display some dummy ad's for testing and development stage.

Here is the answer for it:

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(
                "69AEF8955FAE39BFDF64CDB6D8911089").build();
use the above line of code during testing and development phase.Replace 69..... with the string that u find in your logcat when u run your application.

AdRequest adRequest=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
use the above code during production phase,comment this during testing and development phase.

Comment: Hi Samkit, I think we cannot manually unblock an adMob account because google will block the account if we violate the terms and conditions,if u violate for first time they will block for 1 month by sending you an mail that you have violated the terms ,even if you violate for 2nd time they will permanently block your adMob account, so I suggest you to create an new AdMob account with alternative gmail-id but see that this time you will not violate by following the solution I have posted for getting Live ad's during production and demo ad's during testing phase

Comment: I try to use in incognito mode in chrome and it worked. I had earlier tried after cleaning the cache and disabling the addBlocker extension/s