# AdMob Ads not loading : Getting 403 error

Tags: android, firebase, admob, google-play-services

I have 3 apps in my admob account. First app having "com.sts.matru.notes" packageId and another id is. "com.sts.matru.notes.book". 
I had create 2 separate apps under single project in Firebase.

I want to implement admob into both apps. Ad is successfully working on "com.sts.matru.notes". But, not working on "com.sts.matru.notes.book". 
I am getting following error.

```
12-12 19:26:12.249 1746-6966/? W/Ads: Received error HTTP response code: 403
12-12 19:26:12.249 3158-3169/com.sts.matru.notes.book W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
12-12 19:26:12.249 3158-3158/com.sts.matru.notes.book W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

Let me know, what should I do ?

Comment: follow this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208539/cannot-display-admob-banners-received-error-http-response-code-400-etc

Comment: Sorry, I am getting 403 error, not 400.

Comment: Do you have an unique application ID for each of your apps ? [Check here](https://apps.admob.com/#account/appmgmt:)

Comment: Yes @Benoit.. I have separatee ids on AdMob. and multiple apps under single project on Firebase.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653093/403-that-s-an-error-were-sorry-but-you-do-not-have-access-to-this-page-that

Comment: If you just created your ad a short time ago it might simply take some time until its active. I had that problem a while ago. Just had to be a bit patient.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653093/403-that-s-an-error-were-sorry-but-you-do-not-have-access-to-this-page-that

Comment: Did you get a solution? I am facing the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any proxy enabled on your network ?

Or try to connect with another internet provider with the application, It solved for me.

Comment: No, when i use ad request id of "com.sts.matru.notes" into "com.sts.matru.notes.book" then it will work. If Network Proxy issue is there, then it should be not working with that also.