# Ads not displaying, error 403

Tags: android, firebase, admob

Admob is not displaying ads for my app.Test ads are displaying but real ads are not.

This error should be shown if my account is disabled. But I'm able to log into my admob account.

I also tested it on other phones with different accounts also with different connectivity but still no use.

here is the log

```
W/Ads: Received error HTTP response code: 403
 /myapp.test W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
 /myapp.test W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

---Later added---

Here is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="64dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/baseView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="280dp"
                android:padding="10dp">

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/admain" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how I called ads in the main activity

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.appid));
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(getResources().getString(R.string.test)).build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

This is gradle

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---Later added---

Once ads were displaying. Later my account get blocked.After a month its now active. The apps I made prior to the blocking isn't showing ads. But new apps are showing ads without any issue..

I think the only possible solution is to change the package-name to a different one. It worked for me!

Comment: please share your code as well

Comment: Its a long period after this post is made ..still no reply

Comment: looks like your admob account authentication issue.. try adding test ads.. please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653093/403-that-s-an-error-were-sorry-but-you-do-not-have-access-to-this-page-that

Comment: Sorry that ain't the problem.Once ads were displaying. Later my account get blocked.After a month its now active. The apps I made before blocking isn't showing ads new apps are showing..  also, there is no problem displaying test ads

Comment: Did you get a solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: those apps are still not showing ads..But my new apps are showing ads without any trouble.. my account once got banned and re-established by sending an appeal.. after that incident none of my apps shown any ads ..This question was posted then.. But when i checked testing ads on new apps , it found to be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution for the problem I stated above. I built the app with different packagename and different ad-units were placed and the issue was solved!!

Not a perfect solution but, hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

This happened to my project in progress too. In my case, it was caused by the lack of personal information for AdMob.
After I entered the info below on AdMob console, the ads started to be displayed normally.

Settings -> Contact Name

Payments -> Manage settings -> Business name and address

I hope if this helps someone who faces this issue.