# How to resolve an error 403 in Google Admob

Tags: ios, flutter, admob, ads

full error message:

```
LoadAdError(code: 0, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: Received error HTTP response code: 403, responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: [], loadedAdapterResponseInfo: null), responseExtras: {})
```

By [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913996/ads-not-displaying-error-403), I rechecked everything in my account settings. But everything looks fine. It mentioned package name, where can I find it, in my project or Google account?

This probably could be the reason of GFW of China. I'm not sure. how can I solve this?